# Child not re rendering when child state changed

Tags: react-native, model, parent-child, rerender

I’m using model in child components and I would like to manage visibility by child state variable, but when I click on button(it’s also on child) child state variable is update successfully but child render function not called?
Please review my code and let me correct where i'm wrong.

```
      //Main Parent class
        
        export default class ChatMessageComponent extends Component {
            renderItem = ({ index, item }) => {
                return (
                  <ChatMessageView
                    {...this.props}      
                  />
                )
              };
            }
    
    //ChatMessageView child 
    export default class ChatMessageView extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
          <View style={[styles.container, isMinimize ? { width: screenWidth - scale(20) } : null]}>
                <ChatNoticeView
                  {...this.props}
    
                />
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
    }
    //ChatNoticeView child
    export default class ChatNoticeView extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visibleModal: this.props.isVisible
    }
  }
 renderModAL = () => {
    return (
      <Modal
        visible={this.state.visibleModal}
      >
        <RejectReason
        />
      </Modal>
    )
  }
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
    {this.renderModAL()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

//Model
export default class RejectReason extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: lift the state up https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @SaachiTech,
I added my code please check.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your child's function is bonded with the state which won't get updates when the button is clicked. Either need to use the `getderivedstatefromprops` method to update state or bind the visibility with props. I have update your child component which should show the modal.

```
export default class ChatNoticeView extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visibleModal: this.props.isVisible
    }
  }
 renderModAL = () => {
    return (
      <Modal
        visible={this.props.isVisible}
      >
        <RejectReason
        />
      </Modal>
    )
  }
```

You can read more about getDerivedStateFromProps [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)